# Splitting linear history into two branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repository history that looks like this :

```
A -> B -> C -> N1 -> N2 -> N3 -> D -> E -> F
```

And I would like to transform it into the following history :

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
           \_ N1 -> N2 -> N3
```

Given that I have a clone whose history stops at C, what is the best way to proceed ?  D E F changeset is not conflicting with N1 N2 N3 changeset. Well, at least I hope so ;)

Comment: It seems you only need rebase D on top of C, you don't even need the clone. Some GUI probably lets you do it. I don't know the exact commands, but MQ extension is used for the rebasing, splitting D-E-F into queue and pasting it back on to C.

Comment: @herby I don't think the `rebase` command will help shodanex with his task, so I'd not use the word _rebasing_ to describe the solution. Apart from that, I think `transplant` is simpler, but `mq` will work equally well.

Comment: I was not aware of the second item in "There are situations in which a rebasing process is not allowed:

 - the rebasing point (source) is an ancestor of target
 - the rebasing point (source) is a descendant of target
".

Comment: Rebase should work fine for this, the restriction @herby mentions above no longer applies. Rebase doesn’t use MQ or patches by the way, it does something called null merges (afaik).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to have a clone, you can work in the original repo. You can transplant D, E and F on top of C, creating copies D1, E1 and F1 (which will be identical to the originals, provided that there are no conflicting changes). You'll have this:

```
A -> B -> C -> N1 -> N2 -> N3 -> D -> E -> F
           \_ D1 -> E1 -> F1
```

Then you can strip the originals. See the script below.

```
$ hg update C
$ hg transplant D E F
$ hg strip D
```

You'll have to enable two extensions: `transplant` and `mq`. To do this, add these lines to your `hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
transplant=
mq=
```

**Update:** As of Mercurial 2.0, `graft` (a built-in command) can be used instead of `transplant` here; rebase, as Laurens Holst [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487471/67988), should work equally well.

Comment: @shodanex: I have to add that with my script, you'll end up with two heads on the same branch. If this what you want?

Comment: will `transplant` work if the branch is another? What if you do `hg branch foo` right after `hg up C`?

Comment: @zerkms: If you do `hg branch foo` and `hg commit` after `hg up C`, the changesets will be transplanted into branch foo perfectly well. I probably should have said that in my first comment. :)

Comment: the weird thing is that in `hg` you cannot make empty commit (like you can do in `git`) so you need literally to change something (not handy, but anyway I wondered that it is even possible to modify the history in such way in `hg`)

Comment: @zerkms: Marking working directory as a different branch counts as change. You can make an empty commit that starts a new branch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rebase` for this:

```
hg rebase --source D --dest C
```

This works as of Mercurial 2.0; previously, it used to complain when rebasing onto an ancestor revision, but they removed that.

You have to enable the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), if you haven’t already:

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```